# Importing statements into Quickbooks

Tags: import, finance, quickbooks, accounting

How do I import the following statements into Quickbooks Pro?

1. Bank of America
2. American Express

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quickbooks lets you connect directly to Bank of America and American Express (and a host of other financial institutions) via the following

1. Web Connect
2. Direct Connect

It downloads statements and inserts transactions into appropriate places. There is no programming involved.

Answer (score 0):

This could be possible using the QuickBooks API and a bunch of programming - providing the statements are in an electronic and parseable format. This question could potentially belong on Stackoverflow, assuming you are looking for a programmatic solution.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of service is now called a [Bank Feed](http://support.quickbooks.intuit.com/support/articles/HOW21160), whereas before 2014 it was Online Banking.

American Express has two different online services now. AMEX OPEN requires using the American Express OPEN client for Windows, and does not work for Mac. Regular AMEX does not require a special client, and neither does Bank of America.

[This support weblink](http://support.quickbooks.intuit.com/support/articles/HOW21160) shows how you find if your bank requires
a) Web Connect, where you go to a web page in a browser and download a .QBO file, then import it into QuickBooks, or
b) Direct Connect, which works through QuickBooks connectivity software.

No API access or programming is required.

To learn more about Bank Feeds in general, this QuickBooks article, [Online Banking 101](http://support.quickbooks.intuit.com/Support/Articles/INF27637) is useful.